# Is it possible to keep a table's first column (left) and thread (top) at fixed position with pure css?

Tags: css

```
<view class="left-table">
  <view class="thread">{{data[0][0][0]}}</view>
  <view class="tbody" wx:for="{{data}}" wx:key="{{index}}">{{item[0][1]}}</view>
</view>
<view class="right-table">
  <view class="thread">
    <view wx:for="{{data[0]}}" wx:key="{{index}}" wx:if="{{index !== 0}}">{{item[0]}}</view>
  </view>
  <view class="tbody" wx:for="{{data}}" wx:key="{{index}}">
    <view wx:for="{{item}}" wx:for-item="component" wx:for-index="idx" wx:key="{{idx}}" wx:if="{{idx !== 0}}">
      <view class="grid-data">{{component[1]}}</view>
      <view class="grid-cal">{{component[2]}}</view>
      <view class="grid-cal">{{component[3]}}</view>
    </view>
  </view>
</view>

.left-table {
width:180rpx;
display:block;
flex-direction:column;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
}

.thread {
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100rpx;
}

.thread > view {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width:180rpx;
}

.tbody {
height:250rpx;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.right-table {
  position:relative;
  left:180rpx;
  width: 570rpx;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.tbody > view {
width:180rpx;
display:inline-block;
text-align: center;
}
```

With this implementation now I am able to keep the left first column on screen but the top still scrolls away. Is it possible to also keep the top at fixed position?

Comment: You code is really messy. Try to make it more clear.

Comment: Since you're looking for CSS expertise, make it easy for people who know CSS to answer. Therefore consider replacing the source code of your app with the output of that code (the resulting HTML markup). Also add any attempt at coding this yourself or, alternatively, any research efforts regarding the issue.